# RSS Torrent Software

Tags: software-recommendation, bittorrent, rss

In Windows I used an RSS feed to download a tv series, but Deluge doesnt have that option. Is there a plugin to add that fuction? How do I install and configure it?

If there isn't a plugin which client do you recomend?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a plugin for Deluge, but [flexget](http://flexget.com/) is an RSS torrent downloader that is very easy to configure, extremely flexible and has tight integration to Deluge. I use flexget+Deluge and it works fine.

Take a look [at this](http://flexget.com/wiki/Plugins/deluge) for details on  Deluge integration

Comment: Since what flexget does is actually download the metafiles (.torrend) to a folder on your HDD, you can actually use it with other torrent software, as long as it has a "folder watch" function. I prefer the clean, bundled and yet effective Transmission.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Deluge has an rss feed downloader, but qBitTorrent does and is an excellent client.

## [qbittorrent](http://packages.ubuntu.com/qbittorrent) [image: Install qbittorrent]

See [Comparison of BitTorrent clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BitTorrent_clients)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

KTorrent has rss feed and is an excellent client. If you are using Gnome, then it will install "some" dependencies too, because is a KDE application.

## [ktorrent](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ktorrent) [image: Install ktorrent]

See [Comparison of BitTorrent clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BitTorrent_clients)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the discussion, but...

Deluge has an RSS plugin called YaRSS2. Vuze can handle RSS, too, but it's written in java and so it doesn't integrate well with GNOME. The slightly beefier Miro can, as well, but it either has a bug or plays nanny about what torrents you can download. If you want to use Transmission, there's an insanely complicated-looking setup described [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1583064)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer rtorrent + rtgui, a web GUI for rtorrent.  If you do this, make sure to manually install the latest libtorrent and rtorrent (which needs to configured --with-xmlrpc-c).  [These directions](http://code.google.com/p/rtgui/wiki/CompilingRtorrent) are basically what you need to do, but make sure you use the latest and greatest versions of everything.